# How to publish from sbt-native-packager to Google Container Engine?

Tags: scala, docker, akka, google-kubernetes-engine, sbt-native-packager

I am experimenting with dockerizing my Scala/Akka app: I'm using sbt-native-packager and would like to deploy to GKE. 
It seems I could do that by setting the right values in my `build.sbt` file and then launch it via `sbt docker:publish`.

I am not sure what the values should be in the build.sbt file. For instance, the `dockerRepository` setting should have the form

```
[repository.host[:repository.port]]
```

What would be the right information to put there for a cluster on GKE? Thank you very much for any pointer.

Answer (score 3):

The following build.sbt settings worked for me:

```
dockerBaseImage := "java:8-jre"
packageName in Docker := "you-gcloud-project-id/api"
maintainer in Docker := "Maintainer"
packageSummary := "Package summary"
packageDescription := "Package description"
dockerRepository := Some("us.gcr.io")
```

Steps

1. Substitute your Google Cloud Project ID in the `packageName` field
2. Set `dockerRepository` to whichever [gcr.io
   host](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling)
   you want to use.
3. [Authenticate](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/authorizing) using the Google Cloud SDK
4. Run `sbt docker:publish`